# No such module 'CryptoSwift' in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, compiler-errors, xcode8, cryptoswift

[image]

When I'm converting swift 2.3 to swift 3 happen this error.
I did Product->Clean-> Build, but it didn't work in my project.
How to solve this error. Please help me.

Comment: Did you run the pod install command.

Comment: Yes! I did pod install command.

Comment: In addition to `pod install` try installing the Swift 2.x module from here: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/tree/swift2

Comment: pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => "master" 

I used this pod. But still error happen. @Fennec

Comment: @Fennec, your link is swift 2. I encounter that problem too. My swift is 3.

Comment: @MayPhyu Could try adding it as embedded binary?

Comment: @Fennec, I tried to embedded but it still did not work.  :(

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Dim San Cing's answer, which worked for me was to go to MyProject > Targets > Build Settings

I examined "Framework Search Paths" and found multiple references to the same path. I delete all duplicate references and this resolved my build errors.